# Save .png by webshot in R

Tags: r, png, plotly, htmlwidgets, r-plotly

I'm using webshot to save a png file from HTML :

```
p <- plot_ly(plotly::wind, r = ~r, t = ~t) %>% add_area(color = ~nms)%>%
 layout(radialaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"), orientation = 270)

saveWidget(as.widget(p), "temp.html")
webshot("temp.html",file = "temp.png",cliprect = "viewport")
```

This is giving me a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI4y6.png). It returns a small image in the upper left corner. What should I do to have a full-size image in a center?

Comment: Please could you give a small snippet of the dataset you use to reproduce the plot example?

Comment: @PitterJe, As I mentioned in the code, I have used the wind data set included in plotly package : `plotly::wind`

Comment: perhaps read the instructions on `webshot::webshot()` and increase the scale to get a bigger image. That solves one issue. Then use `magick::image_trim()` to crop it to the image area.

Comment: I have prepared a blog post including various details about webshot2. You can visit it from http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/export-save-r-graphs-with-webshot/