# Faster way to save plotly plot as a pdf file (instead of orca)

Tags: r, plotly, orca

I have a few `plotly` plots that I need to save as pdf/eps files to add to a LaTex report. Currently I'm using `orca` to achieve this but it is quite slow, is there another, faster way to do this?

```
library(plotly)
library(orca)

pname <- plot_ly(...)  # plotly plot object
fname <- 'sample_file' # file name to save plot as

orca(p = pname, file = fname, format = 'pdf', width = 1600, height = 1000)
```

Comment: Have you tried using webshot? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289771/save-png-by-webshot-in-r

Comment: I can do png/jpg by other means but for this specific use case, I'm looking for pdf/eps only.

Comment: webshot can create PDFs as well.  Just take the sample code in the link above, and switch png to pdf.

Comment: I have prepared a blog post including various details about webshot2. You can visit it from http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/export-save-r-graphs-with-webshot/

Comment: @ozturkib Your website presents useful information. But it seems that you disabled mouse actions on your webpage, so visitor can't even copy code from your website?